# I'm following the Nutch tutorial, and getting a "No URLs to fetch" error

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

Following the Apache Nutch tutorial here:

As indicated in the tutorial, I've set the last line of my regex-urlfilter.txt to:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/
```

My nutch-site.xml file contains only the lines

```
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
</property>
```

And my seed.txt file is:

```
http://nutch.apache.org/
```

However, when I crawl with

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

I get a "No URLs to fetch" error. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration looks fine to me. You have made these changes in runtime/local folder right?
seed.txt will be in NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/urls folder and 
regex-urlfilter.txt and nutch-site.xml will be in NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/conf folder

NUTCH_HOME is installation directory